# Comparing list of automobile objects by plate number

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, subclass

Okay so I'm doing an assignment that's fairly complex. Basically I have a class of automobile, then subclasses of it (passenger car, and nonpassenger) and then subclasses of them (subcompact car, small pickuptruck etc). I also have a sorting.java class with various methods of sorting. I am supposed to create an array of automobiles, and them sort them by plate number.

```
Automobile class: 

public class Automobile{
public String Name;
public String Colour;
public String plateNum;

public Automobile (String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum)
{
    Name = eName;
    Colour = eColour;
    plateNum = eplateNum;
}
public String toString()
{
String result = "Name: " + Name +"\n";
result += "Colour: "+Colour+"\n";
result+= "Plate Number: "+ plateNum;

return result;
}


}//end Automobile
```

Passenger car class:

```
abstract public class passengerCar extends Automobile{
public abstract double fee();
public passengerCar (String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum)
{
    super (eName, eColour, eplateNum);

}

public String toString()
{
    String result = super.toString();

    result += "\n Fee: "+fee(); 

    return result;
}


}
```

subcompact class: (example of subclass)

```
public class subCompact extends passengerCar{
public double litres;
public subCompact (String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum, double eLitres)
{
    super (eName, eColour, eplateNum);
    litres = eLitres;

}
public double fee(){
double cost = (litres / 10);
return cost;
}
```

}

Database class:

```
public class CarDataBase{

private Automobile[] database;
private int count;

//creates initially empty database
public CarDataBase()
{
database = new Automobile[100];
count =0;
}


 public void addminiCompact(String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum, double eLitres)
{
    if(count == database.length)
    increasesize();
    database[count] = new miniCompact (eName, eColour, eplateNum, eLitres);
    count++;
}
 public void addsubCompact(String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum, double eLitres)
{
    if(count == database.length)
    increasesize();
    database[count] = new subCompact (eName, eColour, eplateNum, eLitres);
    count++;
}
 public void addCompact(String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum, double eLitres)
{
    if(count == database.length)
    increasesize();
    database[count] = new Compact (eName, eColour, eplateNum, eLitres);
    count++;
}
 public void addMidsize(String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum, double eLitres)
{
    if(count == database.length)
    increasesize();
    database[count] = new Midsize (eName, eColour, eplateNum, eLitres);
    count++;
}
 public void addLarge(String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum, double eLitres)
{
    if(count == database.length)
    increasesize();
    database[count] = new Large (eName, eColour, eplateNum, eLitres);
    count++;
}
 public void addSmallPickup(String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum, double eGvwr)
{
    if(count == database.length)
    increasesize();
    database[count] = new SmallPickup (eName, eColour, eplateNum, eGvwr);
    count++;
}
 public void addStandardPickup(String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum, double eGvwr)
{
    if(count == database.length)
    increasesize();
    database[count] = new StandardPickup (eName, eColour, eplateNum, eGvwr);
    count++;
}
 public void addVan(String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum)
{
    if(count == database.length)
    increasesize();
    database[count] = new Van (eName, eColour, eplateNum);
    count++;
}
 public void addTwoSeater(String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum)
{
    if(count == database.length)
    increasesize();
    database[count] = new TwoSeater (eName, eColour, eplateNum);
    count++;
}
 public void addSpecialPurpose(String eName, String eColour, String eplateNum, double eGvwr)
{
    if(count == database.length)
    increasesize();
    database[count] = new SpecialPurpose (eName, eColour, eplateNum, eGvwr);
    count++;
}
public String toString()
{
String report = "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
report +="Number of Vechicles: "+count+"\n\n";
report+= "Vehicle list:\n\n";
for (int i = 0; i< count; i++)
    {
    report+= database[i]+"\n\n";
    }
return report;
}



private void increasesize()
{
Automobile[] temp = new Automobile[database.length *2];
for (int car = 0; car<database.length; car++)
  temp[car] = database[car];
  database = temp;
}
}
```

Driver Class:

```
public class Driver implements Comparable{
public static void main(String[] args){

CarDataBase db = new CarDataBase();

db.addsubCompact("Ford","blue","ABC123",2500);
db.addSmallPickup("Chevrolet","green","CBA321", 4000);
Sorting.insertionSort(db);
System.out.print(db.toString());


}
}
```

insertion sort method in class Sorting.java

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

// Sorts the specified array of objects using the insertion

// sort algorithm.

//-----------------------------------------------------------------

public static void insertionSort (Comparable[] list)

{

  for (int index = 1; index < list.length; index++)

  {

    Comparable key = list[index];

    int position = index;

// Shift larger values to the right

    while (position > 0 && key.compareTo(list[position-1]) > 0)

    {

      list[position] = list[position-1];

      position--;

    }

    list[position] = key;

  }

}

}
```

Comment: What is your specific question/problem/issue?  You've posted code but you haven't described any problems...

Comment: Create the array or list of automobiles and use a comparator to sort against plate number. Why take the pains of writing an insertion sort algo??

Comment: My problem is that the insertion sort method isn't working properly, even when I attempt to cast db to Comparable. And the assinment states that we must use the insertionSort method as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to implement `Comparable<Automobile>` in Automobile and add the `compareTo(Automobile)` method:

```
    public int compareTo(Automobile o) {
        if (o == null)
           return -1;
        if (this.plateNum == null)
           return 1;
        return this.plateNum.compareTo(o.plateNum);
     }
```

Comment: @user3267872 As a general rule: If you are trying to compare two things, then they need to be comparable. Translation to Java: If you are trying to compare objects of a class, that class must implement `Comparable`. In your case you need to compare `Automobile`s to sort them, so it follows that `Automobile` must implement `Comparable`.

Comment: I added Jeao's code to my Automobile class, and added 

    Sorting.insertionSort(db);
To my Driver, but I get the following error 

Driver.java:10: error: method insertionSort in class Sorting cannot be applied t
o given types;
Sorting.insertionSort(db);
       ^
  required: Comparable[]
  found: CarDataBase
  reason: actual argument CarDataBase cannot be converted to Comparable[] by met
hod invocation conversion

Comment: @user3267872 It has to actually `implement Comparable<Automobile>`. Now you're running into some really basic Java problems. You need to read the official tutorial on [Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html). It is concise and well-written and will answer pretty much all of the questions you had here. Also, you are sorting automobiles, not databases - its the `Automobile` that needs to be comparable, not the `CarDataBase`... please read that tutorial! :)

Comment: Would be great if anyone could help been stuck on this for hours now